# Criar UIView translucida

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Preciso criar uma nova tela (UIView) translúcida em meu app, no estilo de um iAD do iOS 7, mas meu problema é que não faço a menor ideia de como procurar isso.

O que eu achei até agora são coisas antigas, com muitos métodos DEPRECATED ou criando XIB e utilizando QUARTZ.

OBS: Mais ou menos no modelo abaixo, mas translúcida igual a View de notificações do iOS7.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da uma olhada no https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController

Da pra brincar bastante. Você criar uma view controller da maneira que você que e no storyboard você seta o Storyboard ID para poder instancia-la no código, no exemplo abaixo: "nav".

Para abrir um novo View Controller dentro do Form Sheet:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nav"];

// abre o novo view controller
[self mz_presentFormSheetController:vc animated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {
   //seu código
}];
```

O MZFormSheetController automaticamente deixa o background translucido e realiza as animações ao aparecer e sumir. Você pode configurar algumas coisas, como deixar o fundo embaçado:

```
[[MZFormSheetBackgroundWindow appearance] setBackgroundBlurEffect:YES];
[[MZFormSheetBackgroundWindow appearance] setBlurRadius:5.0];
[[MZFormSheetBackgroundWindow appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Bom dia @André. Peço que por favor elabore mais sua resposta, a fim de deixá-la completa. Se um dia o projeto sair do ar, não teremos nada como resposta à pergunta.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, posso elaborar mais a resposta colocando um exemplo de como programar um MZFormSheetController, mas isso é justamente o que tem no github deles. Se um dia o projeto sair do ar, paciencia, outra resposta surgira. Assim como acontece quando sai uma versão nova do iOS e as antigas respostas não servem mais.

Comment: @AndréCytryn O projeto não precisa ser descontinuado para que uma resposta contendo só links perca valor. Ele pode trocar de hospedagem, mudar de dono, ser mesclado com outro projeto. Além disso, adicionar maiores detalhes sobre o projeto à sua resposta também ajuda nos casos em que a documentação original é fraca (como é o caso aqui). Eu editei sua resposta para dar mais corpor à ela, com mais detalhes sobre o MZFormSheetController. Infelizmente, iOS não é a minha, e posso ter cometido alguns erros. Você poderia revisá-la, para garantir que ela continua correta?

Comment: @Gabe Concordo, mas não acho que nesse caso a resposta esteja "mais completa". Podemos adicionar as informações do projeto aqui, mas seria copiar e colar o que tem nas especificações do MZFormSheetController.
Acaba que caímos naquela velha história de dar o peixe ou ensinar a pescar. De qualquer maneira seu complemento está perfeito, isso é o básico para conseguir usar o projeto.

Answer (score 3):

Para deixar a `UIView` *apenas* translúcida, você só precisa configurar a propriedade `alpha` da `UIView` com um valor menor do que `1`.

Uma solução para conseguir o efeito mostrado na sua imagem é criar uma `UIView` com `alpha < 1` servindo como uma máscara intermediária entre a `UIView` no plano de fundo (*background*) e a `UIView` em primeiro plano (*foreground*).

Existe também um outro efeito chamado *blur* que está sendo bastante utilizado ultimamente (especialmente após o lançamento do iOS 7). A criação deste efeito é mais sofisticada que o caso anterior, entretanto existem vários tutoriais e códigos *open source* disponíveis na internet que tratam do assunto.

Comment: Vou procurar por _blur_ acredito que seja esse meu objetivo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Se for realmente o blur que você deseja, basta "roubar" o layer de um UIToolbar, conforme esse tutorial aqui: http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-make-a-realtime-blur-on-ios-7/

Comment: Douglas, bemvindo! Se possível acrescente aqui informação útil do link. Como está, e no caso de o link deixar de funcionar a resposta fica sem senido.